# What is the proper way to apply CRUD operation on DateTime.Now?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I have a SQL Server table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimePeriod](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TimePeriod] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a unit test like the following:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Save()
    {
        OrmEngine.Initalize();

        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        TimePeriod item = new TimePeriod();
        item.Time = dateTime;
        item.Description = item.Time.Millisecond.ToString() + "=Description";

        TimePeriodBllManually bll = new TimePeriodBllManually();
        int newId = bll.Save(item);

        TimePeriod returns = bll.Get(newId);

        Assert.IsNotNull(returns);
        Assert.AreEqual(item.Time, returns.Time);
        Assert.AreEqual(item.Description, returns.Description);
    }
```

**SQL Server data:**

[image]

It seems that time is being changed during the Insert operation. The outcome is the same no matter the SQL datatype is either `datetime` or `datetime2`.

From the C# perspective, I thought, `DateTime` is an immutable type. But, here I see that `dateTime` is changing its value even after the assignment.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: To throw in an open door, have you debugged the test, do the values have exactly the same value?

Comment: Since `DateTime.Now` is not *pure* (its return value depends on something more than its parameters, which as a property are none), it's difficult to test anything that uses it. You need a mockable time source, like `NodaTime`'s `IClock` interface. You can inject an implementation that gives you a deterministic time.

Comment: @madreflection: `DateTime.Now` returns a `DateTime` object.  The object so retrieved is a stable "value."

Comment: Right, but if you use that value to determine what the result of the test should be, your test becomes tautological.

Comment: I assume that to be the case, yes.  Many unit tests are like that.

Comment: Milliseconds are different (items=368, returns=367)

Comment: Would you not question the value of those unit tests?

Comment: There are many unit tests I see people write that provide no probative value; so yes, I would question the value of such tests.

Comment: Can you show the design of the table TimePeriod?

Comment: @AlexLeo, see the edit. Give me some time, I will also post my CRUD source code.

Comment: Why not create a new question? This is now completely different from your original question, don't be a chameleon, just create a new question and reference this one with its answers as it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ticks and the number of milliseconds are going to be different - therefor assert will most likely always fails.

If the number of milliseconds can be overlooked then we look at the total number of seconds in order to do the assertion:

```
        int x = (int)DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;

        int y = (int)DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;


        Assert.AreEqual(x, y);
```

***EDIT***

Following on  Icepickle comments and user366312 extra info - I have done some more digging and I can confirm that the issue is not related to DateTime.

The problem here is a loss of precision when storing a datetime type to database.

As per example from user366312 if we use the following datetime value `DateTime(2020, 7, 25, 15, 10, 20, 30);` there is no loss of precision when storing to db

[image]

However if we use a value coming from DateTime.Now

```
item.Time
{25-Jul-20 12:31:11 AM}
    Date: {25-Jul-20 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 25
    DayOfWeek: Saturday
    DayOfYear: 207
    Hour: 0
    Kind: Local
    Millisecond: 368
    Minute: 31
    Month: 7
    Second: 11
    Ticks: 637312338713680636
    TimeOfDay: {00:31:11.3680636}
    Year: 2020
```

[image]

We would have a loss in precision -resulting in what the `returns` item has provided:

```
returns.Time
{25-Jul-20 12:31:11 AM}
    Date: {25-Jul-20 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 25
    DayOfWeek: Saturday
    DayOfYear: 207
    Hour: 0
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 367
    Minute: 31
    Month: 7
    Second: 11
    Ticks: 637312338713670000
    TimeOfDay: {00:31:11.3670000}
    Year: 2020
```

As it stands the issue would/could be fixed by changing the design of the data type on the database.

The solution provided by user366312 will work - but as pointed out by Icepickle we are reducing/losing the precision.

A more robust implementation would be changing the Time column in the database to `datetime2(7)`

[image]

***EDIT 2 CRUD operation implementation:***

I have created a small application in order to add a 1000 entries in the database. Here is the implementation.

**My environment:**

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  11.0.5058.


Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.6.3
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.6.3+30225.117
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03761

Installed Version: Professional
```

Database table implementation:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimePeriod](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Time] [datetime2](7) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TimePeriod] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

**TimePeriodEntity class**

```
#region Usings

using System;

#endregion

public class TimePeriodEntity
{
    #region Properties

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

**CRUDOperation class**

```
#region Usings

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

#endregion

public static class CRUDOperation
{
    #region Fields

    private const string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Database=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    static DataTable DataTable;

    #endregion

    static CRUDOperation()
    {
        DataTable = new DataTable();
    }

    public static List<TimePeriodEntity> Read()
    {
        List<TimePeriodEntity> list = new List<TimePeriodEntity>();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM TimePeriod";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adaptor.Fill(DataTable);
                foreach (DataRow row in DataTable.Rows)
                {
                    TimePeriodEntity tp = new TimePeriodEntity();
                    tp.ID = (int)row[0];
                    tp.Description = row[1].ToString();
                    tp.Time = Convert.ToDateTime(row[2]);

                    list.Add(tp);
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static void Create(DateTime time)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO TimePeriod(Description,Time) VALUES(@param2,@param3)";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = $"{time.Millisecond} = Description";
            command.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = time;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

}
```

The rows added in the database are in this format:

```
ID  Description         Time
606 142 = Description   2020-07-29 08:37:38.1420528
```

Here is a subset of my result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok - I had a look and I will edit my question with some extra info.

Comment: Nice investigation :) I haven't even seen you did more investigations on the problem. The question itself though doesn't really specify what the DB is that is used behind the scenes so that might be an assumption

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` data type in SQL Server is accurate to 3.33 milliseconds. If you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the type it states:

> Accuracy -  Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

The .936 from your example will be stored as .937, as per design.
Switching to `datetime2` should overcome this behaviour, as it is accurate to 100 nanoseconds, but you have stated that you get the same result using `datetime2`.

Are you able to share code from the data layer ? Possibly there is a portion which is still using `datetime` as the data type and causing the rounding to occur even with the field set to `datetime2`.

Comment: Thanks. Give me some time, I will post my CRUD source code in the OP question body.